# Google Maps v3 InfoBox Event Propagation in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, safari, mobile-safari, dom-events

I have created an infobox using google maps api v3 and [infoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) from the maps utility library .  The infobox has overflow-y data.  Scrolling works exactly as expected on IE, FF, Chrome and Safari desktop.  Scrolling does not work at all, however, in mobile Safari.  It's almost as if the infoBox doesn't detect a touch to start scrolling.

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivceedub/ztNuK/) to demonstrate the problem. As you can see (in the iOS simulator or on an iOS device), the mouseenter, touchstart, mouseleave and touchend events are being triggered just fine; it's just that there is no way to scroll down to see the overflow text.

I've been struggling with this all week.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem and updated the jsfiddle accordingly.  It is clear that the problem deals with event propagation. I'm just too much of a newbie to figure it out.  If I set the infobox option enableEventPropagation to true, then mouseenter and touchstart trigger from within the infobox as expected.  However, setting it to true also stops scrolling the infobox from within mobile safari.  There has to be a way to trigger mouse and touch events while preserving scrolling in mobile safari. I'll accept any hack at this point. Thanks again for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug in mobile safari (pretty likely), infobox.js, or google maps, but for some reason, scrolling won't work inside an infobox on mobile safari if event propagation is enabled on that infobox.  Scrolling will work in other browsers (FF, Chrome and desktop Safari) when event propagation is enabled.  Also, scrolling works just fine in mobile safari with event propagation turned off for the infobox.

So, the hack that I used to solve this problem was simply to determine whether the client was an iOS browser and then set event propagation accordingly.  I know that this approach is hackie, but it was the best that I could come up with.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivceedub/ZCN4C/) for confirmation that it works in both mobile safari and other browsers.  Also, make sure that you're using the most recent version of infobox.js (1.1.11)

Comment: Great catch. Sure, it's hacky, but I don't mind. Thank you for sharing the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For infobox
var myOptions = {
    enableEventPropagation: true
};
$(document).on("click touchstart", ".clickableclass", function() {
    // your function
});
```

touchstart worked for me