# textarea focus/event propagation issues inside an infobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been having significant issues with event propagation inside google maps infoboxes.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728264/google-maps-v3-infobox-event-propagation-in-mobile-safari) SO question for an example.

I now have a new related problem.  When I set the infoBox option enableEventPropagation to true (which I think that I have to do to enable .delegate() commands to work on elements inside of the infoBox), then I can't get focus on a textfield that is inside the infoBox.  By simply setting enableEventPropagation to false (which then disables my needed delegates), focus works exactly as expected.  Is there a way to enable my delegates while not mucking up focus on textareas?

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivceedub/JvBVk/) for an example

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick event to your textarea and set focus to it. Just add

```
onClick="this.focus()"
```

to the textarea tag like so

```
function data() {
var HTML = "<div id='ib' class='infobox_test'>" +
                "<textarea maxlength='249' onClick=\"this.focus()\"></textarea>" +
           "</div>";
return HTML;
```

}

fiddle example found here http://jsfiddle.net/pimlinders/ZJSJ3/

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing for a while and noticed the same problem.
disabled focus and editing capabilities of textarea element when eventPropagation = true;

Try to use focusin/focusout to disable/enable map scroll and drag.
Its not like you might want but if the user is typing in the textarea you can fire those events without problem.